# How to pass a variable from a Store Procedure into a another Store Procedure

Tags: plsql

i have an SP_1 with a variable "RUN_DATE" that stores a date. I have another SP_2, and in this SP_2, i want that SP_1 runs, if and only if, that variable in SP_1 has a date within the last 15 days.

How this is possible?

SP_1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_1"

is

Run_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

Run_DATE := SYSDATE;

// DO STUFF

END;
```

SP_2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_2"

is

//DECLARE VARIABLES

BEGIN

// PSEUDO CODE:

// IF Run_DATE FROM SP_1 < SYSDATE -15 DAYS
// CALL SP_1 AND RUN IT
// ELSE DO NOT CALL SP_1

END;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stores"? Procedures don't "store" values, they are assigned when they are run. So to find out what the value of the variable is, you'd need to run the procedure. Perhaps if you added example code for both procedures to your question, we might be better placed to try and help you achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your Procedures should look something like below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_1(RUN_DATE IN DATE)
IS
    //declare magic variables
BEGIN
    //do magic
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_2(parameters if any)
IS
    //declare variable for RUN_DATE
BEGIN
    IF RUN_DATE_VARIABLE > SYSDATE - 15 
    THEN
        SP_1(RUN_DATE_VARIABLE);
    END IF;
END
```

The above will work unless you are fetching RUN_DATE within SP_1 only, in that case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_2(parameters if any)
IS
    //declare magic variables
BEGIN
    SP_1(parameters if any);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_1(parameters if any)
IS
   //declare RUN_DATE_VARIABLES
BEGIN
   // fetch value of the RUN_DATE variable
   IF RUN_DATE_VARIABLE > SYSDATE - 15
   THEN 
     // do something
   END;
END;
```

Comment: I want SP_2 to recognize the date that is in the SP_1 RUN_DATE variable and if the date is less than the last 15 days, SP_1 should be executed. I have to pass parameters?

Comment: You still can't get the value of a variable from SP_1 without running SP_1 first, even if you pass the value out as a parameter! Do you mean you need to run SP_1  a second time, if SP_2 determines it meets the criteria?

Comment: O will put 2 cenarios. Cenario 1: variable "RUN_DATE" on SP_1 has a date less than SYSDATE - 15, SP_2 will call SP_1 to run it. Cenario 2: variable "RUN_DATE" on SP_1 has a date greater than SYSDATE-15, SP_2 will NOT call the SP_1.

Comment: @PauloSilva How do you calculate or fetch this RUN_DATE in SP_1 ?

Comment: I make RUN_DATE := SYSDATE on SP_1.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample pseudo code of what you expect your two procedures to do. However, if SP_1 assigns sysdate to the run_date variable, isn't that always going to fail your check?

Comment: OK, just put pseudo code. Hope this helps to clarify my question.

Comment: @PauloSilva what you are asking cannot be done and doesn't even make sense. Why not just put the condition inside SP_1, I would suggest you to use the 2nd code layout which I have shared in my answer.